# Implementing SUM(i,j) and CHANGE(i,j) in O(log(n)) using a datastructure with O(n) space complexity

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, heaps, subsequences

I have two operations:

$Sum(i,j)$ : Calculate $A[i]+A[i+1]+....+A[j]$

$Change(i,x)$: Set $A[i]=x$

I need to implement these operations in an appropriate data structure using $O(n)$ space ($n$ is the length of the input array $A$).

The $Sum(i,j)$ procedure needs to have a runtime complexity of $O(\log(n))$ and the $Change(i,x)$ procedure needs to have a runtime of $O(\log(n))$.

I thought about using a heap seeing as change-key in a heap is $O(\log(n))$, but I cant figure out how exactly to get the $Sum(i,j)$ procedure down to $O(\log(n))$. To me it seems you would need $O(n)$ time to do this. If anyone could nudge me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try implementing Segment Trees with Lazy Propagation for updates.

Comment: Thank you sagnik, this seems to be what i am looking for. I am a little confused about the space complexity of segment trees though. ON wikipedia it is stated that the space complexity is O(nlogn) but elsewhere its says it is O(4n)

Comment: Check the answer. I added in the part about space complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What is a Segment Tree?**

It is a data structure which is used to operate over a range of input.

> **How does it work?**

The original elements of the array form the leaves of the tree. Each internal node represents some merging of the sub trees. For example consider the array $A = [1,5,7,8,9,15]$.

If we were to construct a segment tree out of the array with the sum operation in mind, we would have the following tree.[image: segment Tree]

> **What about the run time complexity?**

If we try to implement the $Sum(i,j)$ and $Change(i,x)$ operations via a segment tree, the time complexity would be the following:

- Construction of the Segment Tree: This would take $O(n)$ time.
- $Sum(i,j)$ : This would take $O(\log(n))$ time.
- $Change(i,x)$ : This would take $O(\log(n))$ time.

> **What about the space complexity?**

Being an almost complete binary tree, a Segment tree with $n$ leaf nodes will have $2n — 1$ total nodes. Hence the space complexity will be $O(n)$.

Comment: I have mentioned Lazy Propagation in my comments to the question. Also note that Lazy Propagation is useful only for range updates. Here the change function only updates one element at a time. Hence lazy propagation is strictly not needed.